# react native android use fingerprint for api 23 and newer only

Tags: android, react-native, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I have a react native android app, which uses fingerprint, which requires api 23. That made the app not installable on older devices. Is there a way around this, so I could have the app installable on older phones as well, just without using fingerprint funcionality?

Answer (score 0):

I have created [**this ReactNative Module**](https://github.com/hiteshsahu/FingerPrint-Authentication-With-React-Native-Android) keeping data security as the top priority and it is backward compatible with older versions of Android (API<23).

You can fork my project and start building on top of it.

[image]

**Features**

- Uses FingerprintManagerCompat to Supports Older Version of Android(API<23)
- Error Handling in the case of invalid Finger Prints, Unregistered FingerPrint, Lock is not enabled and not supporting Hardware etc.
- After exceeding max finger print attempts, the plugin disables FingerPrint authentication feature.
- Disables FingerPrint authentication after exceeding max attempts can be enabled after successful login
- User Credentials are Encrypted with AES algorithm and stored in file system while the key is stored in Android Keystore.
- Doesn't work for rooted devices.